# how to get items from 2 sources in one list box

Tags: xml, windows-phone-8

In my wp8 app I have list box and In my list box i have 3 buttons and a text.Buttons get tags from string list and i want to also bind my Texblock with another string list.

But how can I bind textblock with another source

here is my listbox

```
<ListBox Name="URLListBox" Grid.Column="1">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>

                            <Grid Background="Transparent" Margin="0,0,0,3">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="75"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="75"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="75"></ColumnDefinition>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <TextBlock x:Name="surename" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding}" Grid.Column="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                                <Button Tag="{Binding}" Grid.Column="1" Content="download" Height="72"  Name="button1"  Width="80" FontSize="15" Click="addButton_Click"/>
                                <Button Tag="{Binding}" Grid.Column="2" Content="play" Height="72"  Name="play_Click"  Width="80" FontSize="15" Click="play_Click"/>
                                <Button Tag="{Binding}" Grid.Column="3" Content="pause" Height="72"  Name="pause_Click"  Width="80" FontSize="15" Click="pause_Click"/>
                            </Grid>


                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
```

and also another problem is  when you scroll down it goes but when you leave screen it goes up to its original position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

XAML:

```
    <ListBox Name="URLListBox" Grid.Column="1">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Background="Transparent" Margin="0,0,0,3">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="75"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="75"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="75"></ColumnDefinition>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="surename" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding text}" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                    <Button Tag="{Binding b1Tag}" Grid.Column="1" Content="download" Height="72"  Name="button1"  Width="80" FontSize="15" Click="addButton_Click"/>
                    <Button Tag="{Binding b1Tag}" Grid.Column="2" Content="play" Height="72"  Name="play_Click"  Width="80" FontSize="15" Click="play_Click"/>
                    <Button Tag="{Binding b1Tag}" Grid.Column="3" Content="pause" Height="72"  Name="pause_Click"  Width="80" FontSize="15" Click="pause_Click"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

CS:

```
public void LoadData()
{
        List<string> TextData = new List<string> { "Text1", "Text2", "Text3", "Text4" };
        List<string> BtnData = new List<string> { "B1Tag", "B2Tag", "B3Tag", "B4Tag" };
        ObservableCollection<URLListBoxCalss> obj = new ObservableCollection<URLListBoxCalss>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            obj.Add(new URLListBoxCalss(TextData[i], BtnData[i], BtnData[i], BtnData[i]));
        }
        URLListBox.ItemsSource = obj;
    }


public class URLListBoxCalss
{
    public string text { get; set; }
    public string b1Tag { get; set; }
    public string b2Tag { get; set; }
    public string b3Tag { get; set; }

    public URLListBoxCalss() { }

    public URLListBoxCalss(string text, string b1Tag, string b2Tag, string b3Tag)
    {
        this.text = text;
        this.b1Tag = b1Tag;
        this.b2Tag = b2Tag;
        this.b3Tag = b3Tag;
    }   
}
```

Comment: thanks.do you know solition for other problem I write it end of the first post

Answer (score 0):

Use `Concat` to combine your lists. It will create an `IEnumerable` list

In **XAML**, I'm creating the listbox;

```
<ListBox x:Name="listbox"/>
```

In code-behind, **C#**

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var ListOne = new List<string> { "A", "B", "C" };
    var ListTwo = new List<string> { "D", "E", "F" };

    var Combined = ListOne.Concat(ListTwo);

    listbox.ItemsSource = Combined;
 }
```

Comment: i dont understand can u implement on my code . when i write text"{Binding}",how would list box know wich list will i pick ,can you explain more